# Tail-recursive version of function combinations in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

The non-tail-recursive combinations function can be written like this:

```
let rec combinations l k =
  if k <= 0 || k > List.length l then []
  else if k = 1 then List.map (fun x -> [x]) l 
  else 
    let hd, tl = List.hd l, List.tl l in
    combinations tl k |> List.rev_append (List.map (fun x -> hd::x) (combinations tl (k-1)))
```

*Note that I use `List.rev_append` to at least given the `append` a tail recursive version*

It means generate all the combinations if you want to get k elements out of the list.

I am just wondering is it possible to create a total tail-recursive version of `combinations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [*continuation passing style*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style):

```
let combos l k =
    let rec aux l k cont =
        if k <= 0 || k > List.length l then cont []
        else if k = 1 then cont (List.map (fun x -> [x]) l)
        else 
            let hd, tl = List.hd l, List.tl l in
            aux tl k 
            (
                fun res1 -> aux tl (k-1)
                (
                    fun res2 -> cont (List.rev_append (List.map (fun x -> hd::x) res2) res1)
                )
            )
    in aux l k (fun x -> x)
```

This way, you avoid calling something after the recursive call of `aux` at the price of creating an anonymous function that accounts for the "future computation" that shall be done after the "original recursive call".

Comment: Is there any other more natural way?

Comment: @JacksonTale That's exactly what I asked myself, and I have to say I'm not sure. But from my (admittedly very limited) experience, if your original function relies on *more than one* recursive call, a corresponding tail-recursive version is often cumbersome to write.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do continuations-passing-style, as in phimuemue's answer. E.g.

```
let rec prefix_cps tree k =
  match tree with
  | Tip -> k []
  | Node (left,n,right) ->
    prefix_cps left (fun nleft ->
        prefix_cps right (fun nright ->
            k (n :: nleft @ nright)))
let prefix_cps t = prefix_cps t (fun l -> l)
```

However, sometimes we can rearrange the input on the fly:

```
let rec prefix_tr t =
  let rec loop queue = function
    | Tip -> queue
    | Node (l, n, Tip) -> loop (n::queue) l
    | Node (l, k, Node (rl, n, rr)) ->
      loop queue (Node (Node (l, k, rl), n, rr)) in
  loop [] t
```

Comment: could you please give more explanation? What is `Tip`, what's the algorithm? Is this to generate combinations?

Comment: No, it is a prefix traversal of a tree: `type 'a tree = Tip | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree` -- This does not apply to combinations, just a general remark I decided to put here.